# How make my Asp.Net MVC website Secure when login

Tags: model-view-controller

can i write some code to make it secure ?? or what can i do ??
when login in my website make it Not secure As it is shown in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome is showing "Not Secure" if you don't have SSL certificate. If you want to show label "Secure", you need to run your website under HTTPS

Comment: if i make SSL Enabled : True  in project properties this make my webSite Secure or Not ??